# Can we call a Windows cmd command in Java?

Tags: java

Can we call a Windows cmd command in Java? For example, calling the "unzip" command of Windows in a Java program. Would that be difficult?

Comment: In Python, you need to use `subprocess.call("cmd /C unzip", shell=True)`, so I guess you'll also need to prefix your command with `cmd /C` in Java (the `/C` is to close the cmd process after the command finishes, and the `shell=True` suppresses the console window.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. The most basic API which Java SE provides for this is the [`Runtime#exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29). It has some known traps though, this article is an excellent read: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Note that Java SE provides the [`java.util.zip` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) as well for zipping/unzipping files programmatically. See also [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) for a guide.

Comment: Well then I would use java's classes to unzip

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do it,USE

```
**Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");**
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the newer class ProcessBuilder: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

It holds your hand a little bit more and it allows you to merge the error and stdout streams so that you don't have to have two streamgobbler threads running.