# A follow-up question for the unzip/zip in Java

Tags: java, zip

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294733/can-we-call-a-windows-cmd-command-in-java) earlier about unzip/zip using windows cmd command in Java. That turn out to be not good for a program and one would suggest using the java.util.zip to unzip/zip. After looking through some tutorial, I found out usually they just loop through the content of the zip file. If I know the name of the file I want, can I extract it explicitly without looping through the whole zip file??  Here in my case, my zip file have 2300+ entries, and I would only want one of them. Do you guys happen to know some tricks? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find hot to decompress files at: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Instead of looping and extracting all files just locate file you are interested in with `ZipFile.getEntry()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a [ZipEntry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) -object for the specific file from [ZipFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html)-object via the [getEntry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getEntry%28java.lang.String%29)-method. To access the file contents, use ZipFile's [getInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29) with the ZipEntry-object.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for yourself and not your program, have you considered using the `jar` command in the JDK for this?